# How to make a button appear one row with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I am using laravel to display users on the screen from the database.

I display the users in a table where every user is a table row. Also every table row is a seperate form. I want the admin to have the ability to save every row seperate.

```
USERNAME       FIRSTNAME      LAST NAME    SAVE BUTTON
--------------------------------------------------------
[username]    [first name]   [last name]  [ save button]
[ username2]  [firstname]    [last name]  [ save button]
```

So i made a class called 'rowsaver'. Every element in the row has this class. The save buttons have the class 'btnvanish' On document ready i hide the save button:

```
$('.btnvanish').hide();


$('.rowsaver').on('change',function() {
    $('.btnvanish').show();

});
```

When an element in the textfield is changed the save button (at the end of the row)  pops-up.The only problem is that every save button of every row pops up.

I want the save button to pop-up only of the row whoms textfields are changed. Does anyone have an idea how i can accomplish this?

This is one of my table rows:

```
 <tr>
   {{Form::open(array('url' => 'KSMschema')) }}
   <td> {{Form::textarea('Werkwijze',$user->Werkwijze, array('style' => 'height: 30px; overflow: hidden', 'class' => 'form-control textbox rowsaver')) }} </td>
   <td> {{Form::textarea('Werkwijze',$user->Werkwijze, array('style' => 'height: 30px; overflow: hidden', 'class' => 'form-control textbox rowsaver')) }} </td>
   <td>{{Form::submit('Opslaan', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btnvanish'))}}</td>
   {{Form::close()}}
</tr>
```

...

Comment: without seeing any HTML markup, we can only guessing. Maybe: `$(this).find('.btnvanish').show();` Now please post relevant HTML markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code might not be perfect, as I dont see your html, but in general you need to find button according to changed row:

```
$('.rowsaver').on('change',function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.btnvanish').show();
});
```

As it is based on guess little explanation:

`this` - input that changed

`.closest('tr')` - I believe your rows are placed in tr, so find correct row

`.find('.btnvanish').show()` - find button in picked row and show it

I hope that you will get the idea or you can post html, that we can help you with more accurate answer.

Comment: I added the HTML code :D I can't get the code you provided to work :( I think i'm making a mistake here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vNFhp/ working example. If you still get problems, explaing what is happening when you use my code